# Fetch queryset with maximum view counts books

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    description = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)
    view_counts = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
```

Each time a user views a book instance in detailed view the `view_counts` attribute is incremented by 1.

Challenge:

Writting a query that will filter for only two books with highest view counts.

Answer (score 2):

You can [**`.order_by(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) `view_counts` in descending order and then obtain the largest two, so:

```
Book.objects.order_by('-view_counts')[:2]
```

It is however odd that `view_counts` is `NULL`able.

Comment: Hmm sure thanks, sometimes minds go wild and forget common concepts ..